# filesystem implementation for java card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

i was wondering if anybody knows an existing ISO7816 compliant file system implementation for javacard? I do know that there is no API for this and you have to do it yourself but i was wondering that despite numerous questions about that topic i havent found a single implementation for this problem on the internet. Has anyone done this on a decent level of quality or is everybody just hacking the minimum of what is needed?

Comment: From what I've seen its the latter. There was a file system API proposal for Java Card once, but it was sunk. I'm however happy to be proven wrong (and don't call my implementation "minimum" ;) )

Comment: Do you want sample code using filesystem in Javacard?

Comment: I search for java card code that implements a ISO7816- compliant file system, not exactly sure though, how your question is meant

Answer (score 1):

You can refer JavaPurseCrypto applet which is a javacard applet to implement electronic card using file system. It's a sample code located in Javacard kit.

More help: [this link](https://code.google.com/p/jcardsim/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/licel/jcardsim/samples/JavaPurseCrypto/JavaPurseCrypto.java?r=2)

Comment: How does this qualify as **not** "*just hacking the minimum of what is needed*"?

Comment: @Micheal I thought Paul needs an implementation of filesystem in Javacard. Am I wrong? If so I'll delete my answer

Comment: well, just exactly what Michael wrote already. Basically it supports a subset of the A4-Select command.